# Bijection between set of all binary sequences and power set of $\mathbb N$.

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

I found a problem in which I had to construct a bijection between set of all binary sequences and set of all subsets of $\mathbb N$.
Is my solution correct?
$\phi : 2^{\mathbb N}\to \{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ is defined by,
$\phi(\{n_1,n_2,.....\})=$Binary sequence with $1$ only at the positions $n_k$ and $0 $ elsewhere.Is this correct?

Comment: The characteristic function of the set? Yes, that is a bijection.

Comment: To me, $2$ is the same as $\{0,1\}$, especially when talking about sets. So $2^{\Bbb N}$ and $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$ are the same too.

Comment: By $2^{\mathbb N}$ I actually mean $P(\mathbb N)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is a bijection.

Define, for $A \subseteq \Bbb N$, $\varphi(A)=\chi_A \in \{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$ where

$$\chi_A(n) = \begin{cases} 1  &\text{ if } n \in A\\
 0  &\text{ if } n \notin A\end{cases}$$

(Note that a binary sequence is just a function from $\Bbb N$ to $\{0,1\}$) and show $\varphi$ is a bijection:

$\chi_A = \chi_B$ (as functions) iff $A=B$ (as sets) and for any $x \in \{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$ there is some $A \subseteq \Bbb N$ with $\varphi(A)=x$ (as functions).

Both are not hard, and exercises in the definitions. This sort of justifies  the notation $2^X$ for the powerset of $X$ one sometimes sees.